# como puedo sumar los valores que estan en el DECLARE

Tags: oracle-11g

Resulta que tengo dos valores y quiero saber si existe la forma de sumar ambos

```
(sumnac+sumimp).

    DECLARE
    sumnac number;
    sumimp float;
    total number;
BEGIN
    select  sum(valorpeso*TOTALSTOCK) into sumnac from producto where procedencia = 'N' ;
    select  sum(valordolar*totalstock)*628.65 into sumimp  from producto where procedencia = 'I';



    dbms_output.put_line('Informe de valorizacion de bodega :');
    dbms_output.put_line('------------------------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Suma producto nacional: '||sumnac );
    dbms_output.put_line('Suma producto Importado: '||sumimp );
    dbms_output.put_line('Suma Total (Nacional+Importado) : '||total );

END;
```